# Android emulator crashes when I try to run HelloAndroid

Tags: android, android-emulator

LogCat filtered by errors is in the following:

10-17 19:08:18.650: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
   10-17 19:08:18.650: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
   10-17 19:08:18.650: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
   10-17 19:08:18.650: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
   10-17 19:08:31.911: ERROR/BatteryService(51): usbOnlinePath not found
   10-17 19:08:31.911: ERROR/BatteryService(51): batteryVoltagePath not found
   10-17 19:08:31.911: ERROR/BatteryService(51): batteryTemperaturePath not found
   10-17 19:08:31.931: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(51): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
   10-17 19:08:36.251: ERROR/EventHub(51): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
   10-17 19:08:36.251: ERROR/EventHub(51): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
   10-17 19:08:36.381: ERROR/System(51): Failure starting core service
   10-17 19:08:36.381: ERROR/System(51): java.lang.SecurityException
   10-17 19:08:36.381: ERROR/System(51):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
   10-17 19:08:36.381: ERROR/System(51):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
   10-17 19:08:36.381: ERROR/System(51):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
   10-17 19:08:36.381: ERROR/System(51):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:176)
   10-17 19:08:36.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(51): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service
   10-17 19:08:45.626: ERROR/ActivityThread(94): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
   10-17 19:08:47.255: ERROR/ActivityThread(94): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
   10-17 19:08:47.375: ERROR/ActivityThread(94): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
   10-17 19:08:49.196: ERROR/vold(26): Cannot start volume '/sdcard' (volume is not bound)
   10-17 19:08:49.435: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(30): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound
   10-17 19:08:49.466: ERROR/MediaPlayer(51): Unable to to create media player
   10-17 19:08:52.866: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(130): ERROR: thread attach failed
   10-17 19:09:02.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(185): ERROR: thread attach failed

My OS is MAC 10.6.4, I'm using Eclipse Helios Service Release 1 with . I tried to install SDK (android-sdk_r07-mac_x86.zip) and run Hello Android: the first time I've seen hello android on the emulator screen, but from the second time (I destroyed the avd recreated it for the platform 2.1), I received that errors.

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my question because I solved the problem :) I reinstalled the sdk and it works ... may be a problem to submit to android team, I suppose that something wrong happened when I deleted the avd by using the eclipse avd manager...